# Swipe view from bottom to top till x position

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener

i have view as show in image . i want to make that view up when user drag/swipe up or when he click on that view for only given position say only 40% from start area .and same for down when he swipe down it should go to where it was previous . i am trying with onTouch motion event but its not working properly as it going any where is screen how i can restrict in  .

```
float dX, dY;
```

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

```
switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
        dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        view.animate()

                .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                .setDuration(0)
                .start();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
return true;
```

}

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLIPd.png)